# C# .net cant run a exe file in a network drive

Tags: c#, networking

Im trying to run a exe file from a network drive S:
[image]
the system cannot find the path

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Win32;


namespace ConsoleApp69
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
            string InstallPath = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\SMC\RunOnceSessionPlugin", "FixExtend.exe", null);
            string v1 = InstallPath;
            string v2 = "14.2";

            var version1 = new Version(v1);
            var version2 = new Version(v2);

            var result = version1.CompareTo(version2);
            if (result > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Antivirus is up to date");
            }
            else if (result < 0)
            {
                // Here is the file path of the new installation
                Process.Start(@"S:\Symantec_Endpoint_Protection_14.2.1_MP1_Win64 - bit_Client_EN.exe");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Antivirus version is up to date");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

But this strange error appered 
This works with local files but this doesnt work on a network drive
Should i start it in another method

Comment: WHat's the error?

Comment: sorry forgot to add the picture

Comment: 1. Is the drive available to the user? 2. Do you have sufficient permission to access it? 3. Can you console.writeline the path and let us know what it looks like?

Comment: The User has the Permission and the path can be outputted as it should and the network drive was available

Comment: This file name is *exceptionally* long and string comparisions are extremely likely to fail even with short stuff. | It is also worth ponting out that Visual Studio likes to run programms until special user accounts. Ones that have limited rights and thus can not do a lot of things wrong.

Comment: The app Identity and the user Identity are most likely different. It's impossible to tell with this code.

Comment: Which error did you get?

Comment: Ah, the error was cleverly hidden by the TeamViewer dialog box.

Comment: So just to make it clear, if you copy that `S:\....exe` value, and use the Start->Run dialog of Windows, paste that in and hit enter, Symantec installer pops up?

Comment: Can you test access with: var test = Directory.GetFiles("S:");. Under which account is your VS running, admin?